# disable default behaviour of Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using asp.net C#.

I have one html input field, and 3 image buttons (asp.net controls)

- ImageButton 1 = perform delete operation
- ImageButton 2 = perform Edit operation
- ImageButoon 3 = perform duplicate operation

My problem occurs when the user presses the enter key when the input field is in focus.
When he presses the enter key the browser automatically fires by default the next button.
In my case it is the delete operation.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Re-order your buttons?!?! If IE fires the first one by default when you press Enter - don't make the "Delete" your first button.....

Comment: code wont help you because, the problem is that the imageButton (delete) comes right after the input text field, so when the user press enter key the browser automatically fire the next button

Comment: but i dont want it to fire anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure [DefaultButton](http://weblogs.asp.net/skoganti/archive/2004/09/20/231695.aspx) property properly.

Comment: i add a master page... 
so to do so i needed to apply the defaultbutton property to the master page form
this.Master.Page.Form.DefaultButoon = MyButton.UniqueID;

Answer (score 1):

you can also hide a button at the top of your page/form that will attract the attention of IE when you hit enter.

```
<button style='position:absolute;left:-1000px'>IE sux</button>
```

that button won't display on the screen but IE will click it whenever you hit enter. since it has no action on click, nothing will happen.

note: only works in IE9. perhaps useful with the default button option above.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, use the form's defaultbutton property or it you use a panel use that of the panel.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultbutton(VS.80).aspx